# Laravel show blade - Trying to get property '"' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Afternoon,

I am trying to show a team from my league using teams.show.blade but I keep receiving an error "trying to get property 'displayName' of non-object". I have tried every permutation of code to try and show the data to no gain. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I would like the URL to be domain.com/league/{ID}/team/{abbrName}

Route is as domain.com/league/1/team/MIA for Miami and so on

I have got the code sorted until I would like to show the individual team shown from my teams.index.blade.

**Section of teams.show.blade**

```
@extends('layouts.home')
@section('content')

<div class="page-heading" style="background-image:url('/images/teams/banners/{{$team->displayName}}.jpg');">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
<h1 class="page-heading__title">{{$team->cityName}} {{$team->displayName}}<span class="highlight"> Overview</span></h1>
<ol class="page-heading__breadcrumb breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/leagues">League</a></li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/leagues/{{$team->leagueId}}/teams">Teams</a></li>
<li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" style="color:#ffffff;">{{$team->displayName}} 
</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The setup is as follows including code

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/leagues',['uses'=>'LeaguesController@index', 'as'=>'leagues']);
Route::get('/league/{league}',['uses'=>'LeaguesController@show', 'as'=>'leagues.show']);

Route::get('/league/{league}/teams',['uses'=>'TeamsController@index', 'as'=>'teams']);
Route::get('/league/{league}/team/{team}',['uses'=>'TeamsController@show', 'as'=>'teams.show']);
```

**TeamsController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Team;
use App\Models\League;

class TeamsController extends Controller
{

function index(League $league){
    $teams = $league->team;
    return view('teams.index', compact('league','teams'));
}

public function show($abbrName){
    $team = Team::find($abbrName);
    return view('teams.show')->with('team', $team);
}}
```

**Team Model**

```
namespace app\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Team extends Model
{

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'teaminfo';
public $primaryKey = 'teamId';

/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * The attributes that are not mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [];

/**
 * The attributes that are hidden.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [];


/**
 * Fillable fields for a Profile.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'teamId',
    'abbrName',
    'cityName',
    'displayName',
    'divName',
    'offScheme',
    'defScheme',
    'ovrRating',
    'injuryCount',
    'primaryColor',
    'secondaryColor',
    'userName',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'teamId'            => 'integer',
    'abbrName'          => 'string',
    'cityName'          => 'string',
    'displayName'       => 'string',
    'divName'           => 'string',
    'offScheme'         => 'string',
    'defScheme'         => 'string',
    'ovrRating'         => 'string',
    'injuryCount'       => 'string',
    'primaryColor'      => 'string',
    'secondaryColor'    => 'string',
    'userName'          => 'string',
];

    /**
 * Get the profiles for the league.
 */
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Profile');
}
public function league()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\League');
}}
```

Comment: please first `dd($team)` then check is it empty or not

Comment: what does `$abbrName` contains?? is it `teamId` or `abbrName`??

Comment: Snapshot of database https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4uVZ.jpg

Comment: i have asked for the variable value. from where you are sending to this route?? what does the variable contain??

Comment: The variable contains an abbrName ie: Miami Dolphins = MIA

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Team::find()` it uses the model's primary key (`teamId`). This would translate to basically this query `Team::where('id', $abbrName)->first()` which would obviously fail.

In your case you should use

```
$team = Team::where('abbrName', $abbrName)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: I have tried the code provided but it fails unfortunately stating page not found error. I used the find method as suggested by a colleague

Comment: Are you sure you have an entry in your `teams` where `abbrName` is `MIA`?

Comment: Yeah all the teams have, but for example Miami have an abbrName (MIA), displayName (Dolphins), cityName (Miami)

Comment: What does the variable `$abbrName` contain when you debug it: `dd($abbrName)`?

Comment: it shows just the ****number**** that corresponds with the League ID.. ie domain.com/league/*****number*****/team/MIA

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this

```
style="background-image:url('/images/teams/banners/{{$team['displayName']}}.jpg');"
```

Comment: This was a simple copy and paste error when I was trying to format the code to display on stackoverflow that I have corrected. The code I have written does have {{team->displayName}}

Comment: I have used the {{$team['displayName']}} and it shows a blank page

Answer (score 0):

It may be silly but you have

```
 return view('teams.index', compact('league','teams'));
```

In your controller and then you are using team in your blade with no foreach. Fix your typo aswell
teams.show.blade:

```
style="background-image:url('/images/teams/banners/{{$team->displayName}}.jpg');">
```

Comment: The return view team.index blade works as I require it to. It displays 32 teams that correspond to the individual league. I just can't get the teams.show blade to display a team from the league

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
Your Route

```
Route::get('/league/{league}/team/{team}',['uses'=>'TeamsController@show', 'as'=>'teams.show']);
```

is passing two params $league and $team.

Your method is only looking for one.

Try: TeamsController@show

```
public function show($league, $team){
    $team = Team::find($team);
    return view('teams.show')->with('team', $team);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this fails unfortunately

Comment: can you dd($team); before you return the view?

Answer (score 0):

Answer and solution was Cameron's. Thank you all for the responses

```
public function show($league, $team){
    $team = Team::find($team);
    return view('teams.show')->with('team', $team);
}}
```